# How to upload a zip file and unzip and process files via Play framework?

Tags: java, playframework

I understand how to decompress a zip file - https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/

Is retrieving the zip file is the same as processing a single file as below in Play?

```
final Http.MultipartFormData<File> formData = 
         request().body().asMultipartFormData();
final Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> filePart = 
         formData.getFile("file");
final File file = filePart.getFile();
```

Does play have any utility to unzip and process each file? I saw something for scala (https://gist.github.com/owainlewis/1e7d1e68a6818ee4d50e) but don't see anything for Play Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use java.util.zip package or an API your chouce.

Comment: westsoldier does play has any utility ? i don't have to introduce my logic if something already exist in play framework